# How to fix white home page

Tags: magento2, home-page

[image]

My website home is showing blank. How to fix it?

Comment: Go to app/bootstrap.php file and uncomment this line **ini_set('display_errors', 1);** and then refresh page you can see error then.

Comment: Have you checked log files var/log/exception.log & system.log etc..

Comment: use tail -f var/log/exception.log from ssh & check whether any errors are coming..

Answer (score 0):

After following this step i got this error-
 app/bootstrap.php file and uncomment this line ini_set('display_errors', 1);

how to fix this error?

[image]

Comment: What is your PHP version ?

Comment: run this **php -v**

Comment: and this is not an answer so update your queries in question only.

Comment: PHP Version is 7.1

Comment: My Home page is showing blank

Comment: https://rugs.a2hosted.com/ This one is my website link

Answer (score 0):

**Install these 2 extention and restart apache**

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-dom
sudo apt-get install php7.1-xml
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Note: check **PHP** version first before installing above extensions using `php -v`. Above soution is for **PHP version 7.1**.

Comment: When i am putting sudo apt-get install php7.1-dom in my ssh itz showing - "sudo: /bin/sudo must be own by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set"